# Limitar la entrada del usuario a ciertos caracteres

Tags: c++

Esta es la implementación para un programa que básicamente convierte de ADN a ARN. Las bases solo pueden ser G T A C, y cuando se transcribe queda G U A C, o sea solo cambia la T por la U. ¿Cómo hacer para que cuando el usuario inserte otras letras que no sean esas el programa no se ejecute o ponga algún mensaje de error en las bases? Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std; 
class ADN {
   private:
      string secuencia;
   public:
      ADN(string _secuencia);
      string GetSecuencia();
      int Longitud();
      string Transcripcion();
      string GetTranscripcion();

};

ADN::ADN(string _secuencia){
    secuencia=_secuencia;
}
string ADN::GetSecuencia(){
    return secuencia;
}

int ADN::Longitud(){
  return secuencia.length();
}
string ADN::Transcripcion() {
  string out = ""; // Realmente no se si esta bien :p
  for (int i = 0; i <= secuencia.length(); i++)
    out += (secuencia[i] == 'T')? 'U': secuencia[i];
  return out;
}

int main() {
  string Secuencia_ADN = "";               
  cout << "Inserte secuencia de ADN: ";
  cin >> Secuencia_ADN;

  ADN a1(Secuencia_ADN);                   
  cout << "La secuencia de ADN es:" << a1.GetSecuencia() << endl;
  cout << "La longitud de la secuencia es:" << a1.Longitud() << endl;
  cout << "La secuencia de ARN es: " << a1.Transcripcion() << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Puedo poner un cout diciendolo al usuario lo que puede insertar pero eso no me controla el hecho de que el usuario introduzca otro caracter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar un error de lectura, basta con analizar lo leído:

```
std::string Secuencia_ADN = "";               
std::cout << "Inserte secuencia de ADN: ";
std::cin >> Secuencia_ADN;

for (const auto &base : Secuencia_ADN) {
    switch(base) {
        case 'G': case 'T': case 'A': case 'C':
        case 'g': case 't': case 'a': case 'c':
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << base << " no es una base de ADN\n";
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Si añades el código anterior a tu función `main` el `return 1` hará que el programa finalice informando al sistema operativo que algo no salió bien (eso es lo que se interpreta para retornos diferentes a `0`).

#### Propuesta.

Yo, personalmente, sobrecargaría el operador de inyección de datos (`>>`) en la clase que maneja secuencias:

```
struct ADN {
      ADN(string _secuencia);
      string GetSecuencia();
      int Longitud();
      string Transcripcion();
      string GetTranscripcion();
      friend std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, ADN &adn);
   private:
      string secuencia;    
};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, ADN &adn) {
    std::string datos;
    i >> datos;

    for (const auto &d : datos) {
        switch(d) {
            case 'G': case 'T': case 'A': case 'C':
            case 'g': case 't': case 'a': case 'c':
                break;
            default:
                throw std::invalid_argument{datos};
        }
    }

    adn = ADN{datos};
}
```

Si se inserta una secuencia incorrecta, se lanzará una excepción de tipo `std::invalid_argument`. De esta manera, podrías leer secuencias directamente de la consola:

```
int main() {
    ADN a1("");
    cout << "Inserte secuencia de ADN: ";

    try {
        cin >> a1;

        cout << "La secuencia de ADN es:" << a1.GetSecuencia() << endl;
        cout << "La longitud de la secuencia es:" << a1.Longitud() << endl;
        cout << "La secuencia de ARN es: " << a1.Transcripcion() << endl;
    } catch(const std::invalid_argument &e) {
        cout << "Secuencia no valida: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Claro la idea es muy buena y sencilla de implementar, Muchas gracias